# Wireshark, seq & ack numbers

Tags: networking, sequence, wireshark

I'm using wireshark to sniff out a packet I uploaded and I am trying to figure out how the ack got initialized, and how it reached the final number.

Without revealing too much, when my browser first communicates with the server, it says the sequence number is 152461, and the next sequence number is 152871, which is just 152461 + the # of bytes being sent. The 152871 is the final number the ack gets incremented to when the browser initiates TCP communication with the server. However, when it first starts communicating, the seq and ack gets reversed, the seq = 1 and ack = 88705. The ack increments up to 152871. My question is, why does it start at 88705? I know the seq gets increased by every number of bytes being sent, but how does the ack get incremented, and why does it start specifically at 88705?

Answer (score 0):

I think Wireshark displays relative sequence and acknowledgement numbers.

It always shows handshake as `[SYN]Seq=0`, `[SYN, ACK]Seq=0 Ack=1`, `[ACK]Seq=1 Ack=1`.

I'm not sure about your configuration. But seq = 1 and ack = 88705 looks like the second packet sent by your browser (`[ACK]`) during TCP handshake.

I'll just assume 152461 and 88705 are real seq & ack numbers.

So 152461 is the initial random sequence number at client side. 88704 is the initial random sequence number at server side. (88705 == 88704 + 1). Both are random numbers.

The second packet sent by your browser (`[ACK]`) during TCP handshake should contain sequence number of 152462 (152461 + 1) and acknowledge number of 88705 (88704 +1).

---

Edit: I'm not sure how you found out the real sequence number `152461`. Maybe you have different Wireshark configuration or get from other tools.

Wireshark usually displays `[ACK]Seq=1 Ack=1`. The `seq = 1 and ack = 88705` you found may be the handshake, or may be the next packet after that. It should be clearer with a screenshot.

Comment: i see, so wireshark assigns these values randomly?

Comment: @alex067 Wireshark only captures and displays. Wireshark doesn't interfere with anything. Your tcp client (the browser) generates random sequence number. Server side also generates another random number.

Comment: I see, so is it kind of like an alias? its not the real acknowledgement and sequence number, just a representation?

Comment: @alex067 yes those numbers are not real. `Seq=0` is actually 152461, and `Ack=1` is actually 88705. Wireshark displays relative numbers so human can read easily.